# Push down the page when an anchor is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with some blog items. The items are preceded with anchors, and sometimes I directly link to them using `#my-item`.

The thing is, I have a fixed menu on top, and that menu now covers the title because the anchor link hugs the top of my browser.

Is it possible to push this down (by 100px for example)? I can think of a jQuery way on `click()`but as I said, sometimes I come from another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old thread, but since it is still popping up in search results, it should be noted that current CSS provides the `scroll-margin-top` property for that purpose which is widely supported as of 2021.
You can simply use

```
#my-item { scroll-margin-top: 100px; }
```

to push the item down without meddling with margin and padding.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the way anchor jumping behaves by adding negative top-margin to the target and compensate it with the same amount of top-padding. The browser will jump to the position of the negative margin on click, but the target will still have correct spacings.

Here's an [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bs4ek/)

CSS

```
article {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add some padding to the element?

```
<h3 style="padding-top: 100px;">The subheading</h3>
```

The browser will scroll down until the viewport meets the top edge of the element, and the element has 100px of space between the content and the border.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to add a margin or padding to the top of your content. Consider this HTML:

```
<a name="post1234"></a>
<article>
  Lorem ipsum...
</article>
```

When the hash points to `#post1234` the link will be positioned at the top of the screen. So just add padding/margin to the top of the article:

```
article { padding-top: 100px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Add padding to you `a`

```
a.anchor{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    width:1px;
    display: block;
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to know how push down the jump target for all anchors on a page, here it is:

```
/* all anchors and all elements with the anchor class */
a, .anchor { margin-top: -2em; padding-top: 2em; }

/* all anchors with an href attribute */
a[href] { margin-top:0; padding-top: 0; }
```

You could also use `margin-top:unset;` instead of `margin-top:0;`

If you're really feeling dangerous, you could probably use `*[id]` and apply this to everything with an id.  But I probably wouldn't do it.  I don't know.  Give it a shot.  Take a walk on the wild side.

Other answers here seem to include a display setting, but I don't see how that's necessary or helpful.